# porque es el error java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.long?

Tags: java, mysql, webservice

Estoy tratando de conectar una aplicación web service con *MySQL* pero cuando quiero conectar *MYSQL* server me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dado que Biginteger puede almacenar números muy grandes, tan grandes que no pueden ser contenidos en un tipo Long, no es posible hacer la conversión sin posible pérdida de información. Es por eso que se queja Java. Has probado con el método longValue() de BigInteger? Buenas noches.

Comment: Fijate si en el log de application server tenes un stack trace del error. Eso te debería indicar en que clase y en que linea está el problema.

Comment: Hola es que cuando intento establecer la conexión a la base de datos con mysql me pasa eso. y no se porque es. no se donde esta el error. :/ anexe una imagen para que la veas.

Comment: No hay codigo del OP donde pueda utilizar BigInteger o Long, tiene mas relación con el driver de conexión

Comment: Que versión del driver de mysql usas? Prueba otra.

Comment: @Klaimmore que es OP ? perdon no soy muy experto en esto. No es la unica que estoy usando ya intente con diferentes .jar para la conexion pero no nada. tampoco me ha funcionado. lo que pasa esque yo instale mysql y tambien tenia xampp ya instalado, sera que eso puede ser el problema ?

Comment: OP es original poster, o sea tu. Mi comentario era para david

Comment: Amigos actualicen conector, descarguenlo de https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html con extension zip
lo descomprimen, eliminan el anterior, agregan como add/jar Folder, crean un nueva libreria, vinculan el descaomprimido y listo.

Answer (score 2):

hola yo tuve el mismo problema pero ya lo solucione
primero elimina archivo mysql-connector-java de la ruta C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\ide\modules\ext despues en baja el driver https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html, descomprime el archivo, y copia el archivo mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin en la ruta C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\ide\modules\ext
en el netbeans en prestaciones, en controladores selecciona Mysql (Connector/J driver) clic derecho y en personalizar agregar el driver.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder solucionar ese inconveniente, actualicé mi versión del conector (Driver), actualiza según tu servidor de base de datos, en mi caso MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

Yo lo solucioné de otra manera. En vez de utilizar el driver que viene por defecto en el NetBeans agregué un jar folder y agregué al controlador que está en esta paginá https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

Answer (score -1):

Amigos actualicen conector, descarguenlo de https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html    con extension zip
lo descomprimen, eliminan el anterior, agregan como add/jar Folder, crean un nueva libreria, vinculan el descaomprimido y listo.